# Different data types using case when in SQL

Tags: sql

Does the following work? Val is integer column.

```
Select case when val <= 5 then val else "greater than 5" end as val_category from table
```

'Case when' here outputs val (integer value) when val <=5, but otherwise, it outputs a string value "greater than 5". I was wondering if that works in SQL or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try it, you will get a type conversion error.  `case` is an expression that returns a single value, with a well-defined type.

When one branch of a `case` returns a number, then the value is a number -- these are the type conversion rules for SQL.  The string `'greater than 5'` cannot be converted, so you get an error.

So, just do an explicit conversion:

```
select (case when val <= 5
             then cast(val as varchar(255))
             else 'greater than 5'
        end) as val_category
from table
```