# How return different type values in MySQL case statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to cast string value to decimal while creating `JSON_OBJECT` like this

```
select
JSON_OBJECT('value',
case 1
when 1 then CAST('1' as decimal)
when 2 then '2'
end)
```

And result looks like

```
{"value": "1"}
```

but I expected

```
{"value": 1}
```

If second when statement return decimal value like `when 2 then 2` result is correct, but I need to return different types from case statement, decimal in first case and string in second one like

```
{"value": 1}
{"value": "2"}
```

So how should I modify my query to get expected result?

mysql version is 8.0

Comment: A `case` statement can only resolve to one data type and as you have a string type for the value 2 all other values will become strings. reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55944606/243925

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move the `JSON_OBJECT` generation inside the `CASE` construct as follows:

```
SELECT CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN JSON_OBJECT('value', CAST('1' AS DECIMAL))
              WHEN 2 THEN JSON_OBJECT('value', '2')
       END
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wj2zDykswuQh5sKWyy1kjL/3).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this is just one of the nodes inside the json object, so I don't want to take it out of JSON_OBJECT.

Comment: You can nest it. Consider sharing a bigger sample of your json in your post.

Comment: Solved it with smth like [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eTbrK29GnwvPZ2FhCBzr8C/0), so mark your answer as helpful. Thank you